# Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake in Lambda logs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sftp, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

The function of SFTP is working locally and it has the correct configuration.
The problem is with the logs of Lambda that complains about the configuration I believe by giving me an Error: Timed out while waiting for a handshake.

```
const config = {
    host: 'ftp.xxxx.at',
    port: '22',
    username: 'SFTP_xxx',
    password: 'xxx9fBcS45',
    MD5_Fingerprint: 'xxx:8f:5b:1a',
    protocol: "sftp",
    algorithms: {
        serverHostKey: ['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss']
      }
};


// get file
// get sftp file
// here ....
const get = () => {
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sftp.get('./EMRFID_201811210903.csv', null, 'utf8', null);
    }).then((stream) => {
        let body = stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        })
        stream.on('end', () => {

            uploadRFIDsToS3(body)
            // close connection
            sftp.end()
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('catch err:', err)
    })
};
```

-

```
vpc:
  securityGroupIds:
  - sg-01c29be1d8fbxx59 

  subnetdIds:
  - subnet-007a88d9xxea434d
```

-

```
2019-02-18T13:53:51.121Z    e688c7bd-24fc-45a1-a565-f2a4c313f846    catch err: { Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:695:19)
at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5) level: 'client-timeout' }
```

I added VPC and Security Group in AWS and I still get the same error.
I ran out of ideas of how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.
What was wrong is that Lambda was actually going to another function without getting the connection established.
So what I did is that I added await to the connection and other functions that should not interfere with each other to make to work.

To understand more about await go to this link: 
https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

Increase the time-out value for the lambda function. The option to allocate more memory and time-out are some of the settings for any lambda function in aws